# dynamically adding controls does not displayed inside panel in asp.net web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, panel

I have a web form with a table where one row contains panel to add fileupload controls dynamically

the code is as below

```
      <tr> 
     <td  style="width:70%;display:block; overflow:visible;" >
        <asp:Panel ID="ImagePanel" runat="server">
        <uc1:AddNewImage runat="server" id="AddNewImage" /></asp:Panel>
        <asp:Button ID="AddImage"  OnClick="Unnamed_Click" Text="Add New Image" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Model Items" ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="TxtItems"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

In button click event i am adding new usercontrol to ImagePanel using following code

```
        Controls.AddNewImage Obj = (Controls.AddNewImage)LoadControl(@"~/Controls/AddNewImage.ascx");
        this.ImagePanel.Controls.Add(Obj);
```

Problem is only two controls are displayed inside the panel, i need to allow upto five controls, but these controls are not displayed inside panel. What should i need to do to get displayed these controls inside the panel. do i need to set any css for Panel. Panel is inside a  tag.

Answer (score 0):

That's because dynamically added controls are cleared when page PostBack. Simply solution is to add `<asp:HiddenField id="hidCount" runat="server" value="1"/>` and update your click event like this:

```
int count = int.Parse(hidCount.Value)++;
hidCount.Value = count.ToString();
for(i=0;i< count;i++) {
        Controls.AddNewImage Obj = (Controls.AddNewImage)LoadControl(@"~/Controls/AddNewImage.ascx");
        this.ImagePanel.Controls.Add(Obj);
}
```

This will work perfectly.

Comment: Problem solved but that controls are fileupload controls, if user uploades three files into controls, and then he wants to add one more file then in that case all the existing controls and their uploaded files were replaced with new controls, how to solve this.

Comment: Well, you cannot set file upload value from server, so what you have to do is, show images with title and remove button on the top